# endpoint not exist for Mailgun V3 issue with Yii2 extension

Tags: php, ssl, yii2, mailgun

I am using https://github.com/boundstate/yii2-mailgun 
Yii2 extension for Mailgun and extending it on my wrapper class.

i configure as shown in documentation in web.php ,

```
'mailer' => [
            'class' => 'boundstate\mailgun\Mailer',
            'key' => 'key-85886fafb248373bd90a396',// valid key
            'domain' => 'sandbox5d98013abb1749fd94b68.mailgun.org',//valid domain
        ],
```

Now,
when i am using it by,

```
Yii::$app->mailer->compose()
    ->setFrom('valid-email-address')
    ->setTo('valid-email-address')
    ->setSubject("test mail from mailgun api")
    ->send();
```

first , i got issue with SSL for my localhost.

GuzzleHttp\Exception\RequestException
cURL error 60: SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate
↵
Caused by: GuzzleHttp\Ring\Exception\RingException

there is no any configuration to set SSL => false through config as we can do with sendgrid extension.

and also i am facing this error after this,

Mailgun\Connection\Exceptions\MissingEndpoint
The endpoint you've tried to access does not exist. Check your URL
In mailgun Api , they are using "api.mailgun.net" ,although it throws such kind of error ..

Is there any solution for these two issues ??

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can read this issue in github first [#130](https://github.com/mailgun/mailgun-php/issues/130) and [#175](https://github.com/mailgun/mailgun-php/issues/175).

To solve your problem you can manually add this line in your `php.ini`(based on [Comment on that issues](https://github.com/mailgun/mailgun-php/issues/130#issuecomment-218516652))

`[curl]
; A default value for the CURLOPT_CAINFO option. This is required to be an
; absolute path.
curl.cainfo = "C:\php\extras\cacert.pem"`

Or you can use my way, by added it manually with instance `Client adapter` from `guzzle` like this. If you want use ssl, you can set `verify` to `false`

```
use Http\Adapter\Guzzle6\Client;

 $httpClient = Client::createWithConfig([
  'verify' => __DIR__ . '/../config/ca-cert.pem'
]);

$mailgun = new Mailgun(self::$apiKey, $httpClient);
```